# Are Foxfi and PdaNet+ simple usb tethering enablers?

Tags: usb

I Was just thinking why the FoxFi on play store is a little bit expensive.Does  it just enables the USB tethering from  settings does it have something special or a simple USB tethering?

Answer (score 0):

FoxFi enables WiFi Hotspot on your Android phone, with no **tethering plan** or rooting required.

[Recently FoxFi has been merged with PdaNet+](http://foxfi.com/) and still offers extended features to enhance tethering. it is also equipped with additional features such as Bluetooth mode and Wi-Fi direct options in addition to USB tether.

The reason its unique is that it enables users to bypass tethering block especially with certain ISPs such as Sprint Boost Mobile or AT&T without needing root or complex workarounds and such features don't come out cheap.

> You can connect your tablets, computers or game console with WPA2
>   security. FoxFi usage is covered under your phone's existing data plan
>   and secured with WPA2.

If you don't have any tethering block, I guess there is no need to purchase it, rather use the built-in option to tether, or find some alternative gratis software

Comment: Inbuilt teathering